# How to create one hour trial period in paypal

Tags: paypal

Paypal's doc says that `TRIALBILLINGPERIOD` can be set to : `Day`, `Week`, `SemiMonth`, `Month`, `Year`

If I select Day and set `TRIALBILLINGFREQUENCY` to 1/24 (0.041), will it give me 1 hour trial period ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  It can only be set to Day, Week, SemiMonth, Month.  It can't be set to bill every minute or hour for example.